# Multi-destination route (google maps on iOS) return void json

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, routes, polyline

I'm a newbie iOS programmer and I'm having problems using google's Api "directions" for (multipath/multiroute) on iOS (8.x): 
when i ask to draw a route between two location (origin/destination) there aren't any problems but if i add even one more location, the request to web service return a json with no elements.

My url (for the request) is something like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.853900,14.246600&destination=45.120000,12.535900&waypoints=optimize:true%7C41.910000,12.535900&mode=driving&key=API_KEY

I have already enabled the API's (directions, static maps, google maps for iOS). The api key has been generated today and seems ok.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE that the coordinate "45.120000, 12.535900" is WRONG

the RIGHT ONE is: "45.463817, 9.193010"

Comment: UPDATE: 

also trying with the right coordinates or even with other ones (lat:42.3499 long: 13.3994), i'm having "NOT_FOUND" (as response) in the app but in the browser it works like a charm (status= OK)....

Answer (score 0):

Your URL request works for me. I'm getting zero results because your destination coordinate is middle of the ocean.

Make sure your API key iOS key when testing on iOS device and browser key when testing on your browser.

Comment: wow, that sounds weird for me... o.O
i got those coordinate directly from google maps and they should correspond to Naples (origin), Rome (waypoint) and Milan (destination)...

Which coordinate for you ends in the middle of the ocean?

PS: i'm sure about my iOS key (and returns always zero results) but not so sure about my browser key.. however from the app i always got zero results (i tried with two different users/key)

Comment: ooh, okok, my fault ^^ in my cut/copy testing i lost milan's right longitude xD 

however, also trying with the right coordinates or even with other ones (lat:42.3499 long: 13.3994), i'm having "NOT_FOUND" (as response) in the app but in the browser it works like a charm (status= OK)....
 
PS: i used the same api key both in the iOS app and in the browser. 
If in the browser i try to use an api key generated for the browsers i got "REQUEST_DENIED - key expired"